# Making an Angular2 POST with JSON

Tags: python, json, angular, flask, angular2-services

I have a simple Flask backend for the API, and want to make a POST.
I'm not sure the error is-I get the error message, but am unsure if its an Angular or Flask issue. I tried request.get_json() in my Flask, and got

> {BadRequest}400 BadRequest: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that
>   this server could not understand

Angular2 call in my service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Injectable()
export class NicksService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  nickUrl: string = "http://localhost:5000/nick";
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // Send the nick to the server to see if it is valid
  checkNickValidity(nickName: string): Observable<string>{

    return  this.http.post(this.nickUrl, JSON.stringify({nick: nickName}), {headers: this.headers})
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

Flask backend:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask.ext.api import FlaskAPI
from flask import request

app = FlaskAPI(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/nick', methods=['POST'])
def check_nick():

    try:
        nick = request.json
        if nick =='AmandaPanda':
            return 'Good'
        else:
            return 'No nick found'
    except:
        return 'error'



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: 400 usually means the server cannot accept your request because the request is not in the expected form. It could content-type, request parameter, url, headers, etc. You need to check the server to identify the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have problems on both sides of your application.

**Client side:**

Angular's [Http's post](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html#!#post-anchor) method receives any object in for the body parameter, meaning you don't need to stringify it.

E.g.:

```
this.http.post(this.nickUrl, {nick: nickName}, {headers: this.headers})
```

**Server side:**

Once the client's request arrived properly to the server, you are not getting the data properly.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
from flask import jsonify

(... your code ...)

    data = request.json
    nick = data.get('nick')
    if nick == 'AmandaPanda':
        return jsonify({'message': 'good'}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({'message': 'no nick found'}), 400
```

Here, the json data is stored as a dictionary in the variable `data`. Later, the nick is obtained from the `nick` key of said dictionary.

Finally, it is a better practice to return to the client in json form. That's what [Flask's jsonify](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify) method is for. Notice the 200 and 400 [status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) appended to the response, to indicate to the client if the request was properly accepted (200) or if it was a bad request (400).